# Linux Rsyslogd Configuration

Tags: linux, configuration, rsyslog

I need to modify a couple of things in the configuration of `rsyslogd` thus this gets me to this file: `/etc/rsyslogd.conf`. I want to make rule, more precisely a filter condition. I want to select all mesages of **facility mail** with **the priority at least notice, but not err** and save them in a different file.

Therefore, it would go something like this:

```
mail.notice /var/log/myfile.log
mail.warning /var/log/myfile.log
mail.crit /var/log/myfile.log
# and so on
```

My question is: Is there a easier way to filter those out, than typing each one? The only documentation I found about this topic is [here](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-Viewing_and_Managing_Log_Files.html). I didn't really get from that doc if you can do what I am asking or not, so I thought it would be a great question for stack :D.

Also: I want to filter all messages of **priority crit** but not **facility mail and news**. Same question as above.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it there in the code example is wrong.
A very good explanatory example can fe found **[here](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf_examples.html)**.

Comment: Please add the actual answer.